# Gmail Actions - Confirm Action button error: "Unable to send request to gmail.com."

Tags: gmail, google-schemas

I am trying to test Gmail's Actions in the Inbox, specifically the Confirm Action (https://developers.google.com/gmail/actions/reference/one-click-action#confirm_action). I have written a script using Google's Apps Script to embed this JSON into an email:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "EmailMessage",
    "action": {
        "@type": "ConfirmAction",
        "name": "Confirm Password Change",
        "handler": {
            "@type": "HttpActionHandler",
            "url": "https://aerobic-forge-659.appspot.com?test=677"
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

which is then sent to myself. When I receive the email, the Confirm Action button appears properly, but when I click it, I get an error that reads "Unable to send request to gmail.com". I have access to a log of hits to the servlet page, and according to the log, the page is not being accessed at all by the action button.

The servlet to which the request is supposedly being sent is hosted by Google Apps Engine at this url: https://aerobic-forge-659.appspot.com/ . It works as it is supposed to if the url is typed directly into the browser. Here is the code for it:

```
public class DemoServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws IOException {
        resp.setContentType("text/plain");
        resp.getWriter().println("{ \"name\": \"World\" }");
        resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);

    }

    @Override
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws IOException {
        resp.setContentType("text/plain");
        resp.getWriter().println("{ \"name\": \"World\" }");
        resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);

    }
}
```

I have scoured the internet trying to find a solution to this problem and have been unsuccessful so far. I've made sure to use a secure url for the server, I am sending emails using Google's script (so I know they are properly authenticated), and I am sending emails only to my own email address (so I do not yet need to register with Google). Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.